# Manage date and hours in a form

Tags: php, database, forms

I have three little questions about managing dates and times in a form.
In particular I have a form like this:

```
Date: <br><input type="date" name="data"  ><br>
Start: <br><input type="time" name="start" min="09:30:00" max="16:30:00" ><br>
End: <br><input type="time" name="end" min="10:00:00" max="18:30:00"><br>
```

And I don't know how implement 3 things.

1) In the date field it should not be possible to select the days before to the current one.

2) in the time field it should be possible only to select 30 minute intervals (9:30 am - 10:00 am - 10:30 am ..)

3) I would like that when a reservation is made through this form the time field is increased of 1 hour. So if someone books as the end time 10am, the DB is marked 11. It's possible?
In use in my input.php ( linked to the form )

```
$start_time = $_POST['start'];
$end_time = $_POST['end'];
```

Thanks for the time you have dedicated to me :)

Comment: Welcome. 1: `<input type="date"` also supports the `min` and `max` attributes, get the current date and set it as `min`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date 2: `<input type="time"` supports a `step` attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: If you want all this functionality and want it to work the same across browsers, you should think about using a library or build your own instead. Not all browsers support the above suggested features.

Comment: thank you for your answer. What about the third problem ? Did you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two questions are addresses in the comments, to answer your third question, you can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to manipulate dates and times easily.

Here is an example that increments an hour and returns the new hour value. Make sure that if your hour parameters allow an added hour to roll over to the next day, you handle that case.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$endTime = '10:00';

$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $endTime);
$dateInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 hour');

$dateTime->add($dateInterval);

$newTime = $dateTime->format('H:i');

echo $newTime.PHP_EOL;
```